# How to cancel a file upload?

Tags: html, file-upload

I want to know how I can cancel a file upload with a form `multipart/form-data`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the form post to a hidden `iframe`. Change the `iframe` `src` when you want to cancel. The browser will reload the `iframe` and cancel the previous `POST` request on it.

Comment: I've done it, but according to fiddler upload haven't been interrupted.

Answer (score 2):

The upload is a user's browser POSTing the data up to the server.  You'll need to cancel it on the user-side.  Unfortunately, JS is single-threaded (usually) so it's hard to interrupt it.

You can use JavaScript to change the upload URL (to nothing, LocalHost, etc) if you first have the upload pointed to an iFrame. You can change the iFrame SRC mid-stream. You can also refresh the page or take the user to a new page from the iFrame back to the parent.

These iFrame tricks are ways to 'interrupt the upload on the main page'.

You can also provide cancel buttons that should capture user events (clicks) that change the URL of the page