# How to cancel a file upload when clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a a form which contains a file input, upload button and cancel button:

```
<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' 
 enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' 
 onsubmit='stopImageUpload(this);' class='imageuploadform' >
   <p class='imagef1_upload_form' align='center'>
      <label>Image File: 
        <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' />
      </label>
      <input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' />   
      </label>
   </p>
   <p class='imagef1_cancel' align='center'>
     <label>
       <input type='button' name='imageCancel' class='imageCancel' value='Cancel' />
     </label>
   </p> 
   <iframe class='upload_target' name='upload_target' src='#' style='width:0;height:0;border:0px;solid;#fff;'>
   </iframe>
</form>
```

What I want to know is how can I cancel the file upload when user clicks on the cancel button?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654174/how-to-cancel-a-file-upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think changing target iframe "src" attribute or content aborts uploading.

```
$(".imageCancel").click(function() {
    $(".upload_target").attr("src","#");
});​​
```