# How to not insert database row if file upload is canceled

Tags: php

I have a cancel button in the form below where if the user is uploading a file, they can click on the "Cancel" button to cancel an upload if they wish. But my the problem I have is that no matter what if the file is in the uploading process, it is always inserting a row into the database containing the file name. What I want is that if an existing or new file is uploaded into the "ImageFiles" folder in the server then insert a database row containing the file name else if upload is cancelled then don't insert a database row, is this possible?

Below is the current form code:

```
var $fileImage = $("<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='return startImageUpload(this);' class='imageuploadform' >" + 
  "Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/><br/><label class='imagelbl'>" + 
  "<input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' /></label>" +     
  "</p><p class='imagef1_cancel' align='center'></p>" +
  "<iframe class='upload_target' name='upload_target' src='#' style='width:0;height:0;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>");
```

Below is the imageupload.php script where it uploads the files and where it inserts the database rows:

```
<?php

session_start();


...//Connect to DB

$result = 0;

if( is_file("ImageFiles/".$_FILES['fileImage']['name'])) {
    $parts = explode(".",$_FILES['fileImage']['name']);
    $ext = array_pop($parts);
    $base = implode(".",$parts);
    $n = 2;

    while( is_file("ImageFiles/".$base."_".$n.".".$ext)) $n++;
    $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] = $base."_".$n.".".$ext;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
    "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
    $result = 1;

    $imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) 
    VALUES ('ImageFiles/".mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."')";

    mysql_query($imagesql);

}
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
      "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
      $result = 1;

        $imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) 
        VALUES ('ImageFiles/".mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."')";

mysql_query($imagesql);

      }


      mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: how do you do your `cancel` ?

Comment: A simple way, would be to give the file input a unique name, i.e. from `<?= md5(); ?>` and on uploading and inserting into the database, store this unique name. Then, if the user clicks cancel, you can use the same unique name as a means of deleting the file from the database.

Comment: @NiftyDude I do my cancel by removing the iframe so that it does not upload it into "ImageFiles" folder. Did it like this: `$("iframe[name='upload_target']").attr("src", "javascript:'<html></html>'");`.

Comment: @Gavin  Can you show me in your answer actually where and how to place the <? = md5(); ?> code, never heard of this code before.

Comment: Changing the `iframe` src doesn't actually stop any HTTP request you are doing, even if you do `$().remove()`....

Comment: @NiftyDude The reason I am removing iframe is so file doesn't get uploaded into the ImageFile folder. Do you think I could remove iframe and the make the cancel button a reset button? Do you think that could disrupt the form submit as stated in answer below?

Comment: may sound stupid, but why not wait till file is uploaded completely and THEN (on success) insert a row into the db? Is there any specific reason why you could not go for this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested in a comment, here is the Key method.

```
<?
    if(!empty($_FILES) && !isset($_POST['Cancel'])) // only process if we haven't clicked Cancel
    {
        foreach($_FILES as $Key => $File) // loop through the files as we don't know the input file name.
        {
            if($File['size'] > 0) // check it has a size
            {
                // do insert, making sure you store $Key with the image
                mysql_query("insert into Image (ImageFile, Key) values ('{$File['name']}', '$Key'");
            }
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['Cancel']) && !empty($_POST['Cancel'])) // if we have clicked cancel
    {
        $Key = array_shift($_POST['Cancel']); // get the unique key from the post.
        mysql_query("delete from Image where Key = '$Key'"); // delete the file from the database.
    }
?>
```

The above is your PHP code that processes the upload and cancel.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <? $Key = md5(); ?> <!-- Create the unique key -->
    <input type="file" name="<?= $Key; ?>" /> <!-- Set the File input name to the unique key to be accessed via the server. -->
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    <input type="submit" name="Cancel[<?= $Key; ?>]" value="Cancel" /> <!-- Set the Cancel submit name to include the unique key to be accessed when clicking Cancel -->
</form>
```

Above is the form.

Comment: Key doesn't have to be in a field in the database does it?

Comment: Yes, you would need to add a field called `Key` (or you can change it to something else) for this to work. Basically, it works on you assigning a link between your current upload and that row in the database. If you click cancel, it would then delete any rows in the database with that `Key`, thus deleting the just uploaded file. That said, a simple check would be to use the `$_FILES['fileImage']['size']` to ensure a file has been uploaded before inserting into the database. If you click cancel or stop the upload by pressing escape, `$_FILES['fileImage']['size']` "should" be 0.

Comment: Yep you are right, if the file size is 0, it doesn't insert the db row. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

After the insert statement, get the inserted id: `mysql_insert_id();`

When the cancel button is pressed you can delete the row for the inserted id

Comment: Can you show me how the mysql_insert_id() code should be written in my code above, it would be very helpful as I never used this command before. Thanks for answer btw

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654174/how-to-cancel-a-file-upload) post changing your iframe src on click of cancel button should reset the posted data, even if the form is submitted `$_FILES['fileImage']['error']` should be set if the form submission with file upload is reset (just a guess), i haven't tried it myself but i guess its an option worth an attempt.

Else if the whole form has only the file upload field you could make the cancel button an `input type="reset"` which should disrupt the form submit with file upload thereby preventing the insert operation.

Comment: I tried changing the "cancel" button from type=button to type=reset but still inserting a row into the database